# fletとcl-fletの差異

Tags: elisp

Emacs Lisp で `(require 'cl)` を避けるために、等価な代替として cl-lib を使ってコードを書いたところ、予想に反する結果を得ました。

```lisp
(defun foo () (get-buffer "hoge"))
(cl-flet ((get-buffer (buf-or-name)
                      (car-safe (member buf-or-name '("hoge" "fuga")))))
  (or (get-buffer "hoge") (error "A"))
  (or (foo)               (error "B")))
```

エラーなしに `"hoge"` が返ることを期待しましたが、実際には `(error "B")` に到達しました。 `(error "A")`ではないので、最初の `(get-buffer)` は期待通りに動作してるようです。

cl-libではなく、clパッケージの`flet`を利用すれば問題はありませんでした。

```lisp
(require 'cl)
(defun foo () (get-buffer "hoge"))
(flet ((get-buffer (buf-or-name)
                   (car-safe (member buf-or-name '("hoge" "fuga")))))
  (or (get-buffer "hoge") (error "A"))
  (or (foo)               (error "B")))
```

なぜでしょうか。

Comment: cl-fletを使っている2箇所の末尾括弧が余分のようです (編集したいけど字数が足りない)

Comment: @kosh ありがとうこざいます! (最初はまとめて`C-x C-e`するために`when t`で括ってたので消し忘れです…)

Answer (score 2):

[cl-lib](http://elpa.gnu.org/packages/cl-lib.html)は Common Lisp 風の機能を提供するための cl パッケージに代るライブラリですが、全ての機能で既存のclパッケージとの互換性があるわけではありません。

`cl.el`の`flet`のdoc stringには以下のようにあります。

> This is an analogue of a dynamically scoped `let' that operates on the function
>   cell of FUNCs rather than their value cell.
>   If you want the Common-Lisp style of `flet', you should use `cl-flet'.
>   The FORMs are evaluated with the specified function definitions in place,
>   then the definitions are undone (the FUNCs go back to their previous
>   definitions, or lack thereof).
>
> *Emacs 24.4.1に含まれる`cl.el.gz`より引用*
>   *Copyright (C) 2012-2014 Free Software Foundation, Inc.*

Emacs Lisp はデフォルトの変数スコープがダイナミックスコープで、`let`で束縛された変数は`let`内から呼ばれたいかなる場所からもその値を指すようになります。`cl.el`で定義された`flet`も、そのような振舞をします。

ところがそれは、 Common Lisp の `flet` とは異なるようで、cl-libパッケージの `cl-flet` は Common Lisp に近い挙動をするように改められました。

つまり、外側で定義された函数から呼び出される函数を置換する目的では `cl-flet` を `flet`の代替として利用することができません。

解決策は以下のいづれかです。

1. `(eval-when-compile (require 'cl))` で、コンパイル時のみclパッケージを読み込む
2. 「お作法」を気にせずに、 `(require 'cl)` で実行時にclパッケージを読み込む
3. [nicferrier/emacs-noflet](https://github.com/nicferrier/emacs-noflet)を導入し、`noflet`マクロを利用する

自分の`.emacs`など影響範囲の狭いところでなら、2でも問題ありませんが、私は3の`noflet`を利用しました。`flet`と同じ感覚で利用できるようです。

Comment: ElispとCommon Lispとの比較ですが、スコープの問題というよりも、Emacs Lispにはローカル関数がないということが最大の差異ではないでしょうか。
Elispのfletはダイナミックスコープという表現がありますが、大域関数しかない土台の上で、局所的に代入して範囲を抜けたら元に戻すということをしていますので、言語仕様が実現しているスコープではないと思います。
cl-fletもマクロを展開して眺めてみましたが、コードを解析して名前が競合しないようにリネームし、funcallしているようです。
この場合は、lexical-binding: tにすればCLの挙動により近付きますがローカル関数がないことには変わりありません。
(最近の仕様変更等でローカル関数がElispに導入されていましたら、ごめんなさい。一応調べてみましたが、言語仕様にローカル関数は導入されていないようでした)

Answer (score 2):

Jisami Zonu Tsugioさんの回答の通りcl.elと、cl-lib.elとの互換性の無さが原因だそうですが、
https://ja.stackoverflow.com/a/5459/3510
fletをマクロ展開すると、cl-letfが出てきますので、これを使えば、cl-lib.el に収録されている範囲で書き換えが可能ではないでしょうか。

```
(require 'cl-lib)

(defun foo () (get-buffer "hoge"))
(cl-letf (((symbol-function 'get-buffer)
           (lambda (buf-or-name)
             (car-safe
              (member buf-or-name
                      '("hoge" "fuga"))))))
  (or (get-buffer "hoge")
      (error "A"))
  (or (foo)
      (error "B")))
;=> "hoge"
```

参考: fletのマクロ展開

```
(flet ((get-buffer (buf-or-name)
          (car-safe (member buf-or-name '("hoge" "fuga")))))
   (or (get-buffer "hoge") (error "A"))
  (or (foo)))
===>
(letf
    (((symbol-function 'get-buffer)
       (cl-function
        (lambda
            (buf-or-name)
          (cl-block get-buffer
            (car-safe
             (member buf-or-name
                     '("hoge" "fuga"))))))))
  (or
   (get-buffer "hoge")
   (error "A"))
  (or
   (foo)))
```